# Running 64-bit Virtual Linux on any AMD/Intel Chip without VT-X support

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Am I correct in assuming that a 32-bit virtual machine will run on any AMD/Intel chip, but not always if I want to run 64-bit guest machine?

The host machine has to be VT-x capable and enabled for AMD and Intel?

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, you presume correctly.

Long answer: based on the consensus of [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=75989), and I quote:

> It is required for all 64-bit guests and the Windows guest => version 8.* either 32-bit or 64-bit.

, it becomes clear, that you cannot run a 64-bit guest machine without [VT](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/intel-virtualization-technology.html)-x.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not exactly. 
VT-X is an extension for virtualisation, enabling the guest system direct access to certain resources. 
It is used by hypervisors ("VMWare" "Virtual Box" etc.).
If you want to run a 64bit Guest system, you need to have a 64bit Host machine. But you can run a 32bit Guest system on any Host (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: I want to run a few Linux OS as virtual machines on my 64-bit HP 655 laptop. My processor, an AMD E2-Series E2-1800, does not have VT-X support as I have had some issues. So if I stick with 32-bit versions instead, will that do it?

Comment: Sure. why not give it a try ? :-)

Comment: @gerhardd. In your answer seems you've mistaken VT-d for VT-x. The former allows e.g. PCI passthrough to guests. And nope, you can run a 64bit guest on a 32bit host OS, see e.g. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

Comment: That was also new to me..

Answer (score -2):

There is an answer to this question right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198

> The easiest way to check your workstation is to download the VMware
>   Processor Check for 64-Bit Compatibility tool from the VMware website.
>
> You can't run a 64-bit VM session on a 32-bit processor. However, you
>   can run a 64-bit VM session if you have a 64-bit processor but have
>   installed a 32-bit host OS and your processor supports the right
>   extensions. The tool linked above will tell you if yours does.

What counts for VMWare also counts for VirtualBox in this case.

VT-x (Intel) and AMD-V (AMD) are only to boost the virtual machines performance but it should also work without these, I'm not 100% sure about this, try and see.

Comment: I am pretty sure in the vmware technology, despite running a 64-bit host, that you have to have VT-x to be able to run 64 bits VMs.

Comment: Thank you.. didn't know that, but checked it. It's correct